# Just installed a new sconce. When I turn it on, I blow a fuse!!! Help?

Tags: electrical

I moved to this house a year and a half ago and have replaced about 9  sconces so far with no problems. I replaced one tonight, and when I went to turn it on, I blew a fuse! Never happened before. I had to wait a whole hour to be able to reset it and the second I tried it again the lights went out again :( I think this might be the only sconce that has 2 switches to turn it on. I didn't change the switches though, only the light.  Help! I don't want to call an electrician like google suggests. They are extremely expensive and scarce around these parts!

Comment: Sounds like you got the one of the travellers for the 3 way switch connected to the neutral.  It *might* be possible to determine the correct wiring with good pictures inside of all three boxes, but I'd call an electrician to sort it out.  It's cheaper than burning your house down.

Comment: Your wires are connected wrong, next step is pictures of the wires.

Comment: Can you get us photos of the insides of the boxes?

Comment: You say you had to wait an hour. Why was that?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. Requests for wiring details haven't been addressed.

Answer (score 1):

If all you changed was the light fixture the Hot and neutral may be reversed with a grounded fixture when you turn the power on it goes to ground tripping the breaker try reversing the fixture connections as that should fix the problem if this was the only change. Many times wiring in switch loops are not properly marked and are easy to get reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Without a picture to look at it's hard to know. I'm going to guess that you've nicked the insulation on a wire and exposed some of the copper  or some wires made contact when you put everything back in the box. 
I'm making an assumption that you have three wires in the box: one **black**, one **white**, and one **bare copper** (it might be **green**, but that's rare in house wiring). It's not unusual in older houses to only have a black and white wire, with no bare copper. Either way, the black and white should land on the posts that power the light, the bare (if it is there) should go to the ground screw (in a newer light this should be a green screw). If there is no bare copper wire, nothing should be run to the ground screw. If all that is correct then my recommendation:

- Turn the breaker off (or pull the fuse if you actually have a
  fusebox).
- pull the sconce off the box/wall.
- Examine the wires and light. If you've been tripping a breaker/blowing a fuse and the problem is in the lightbox, you will have black marks where the arc has been burning material.
- depending on the burn, you may have to get an electrician to run new wires.
- If you have enough wire in good shape, I would suggest using electrical tape (high quality: Scotch 33 for me) around all connections. When you push the wires back into the box sometimes wires come together in a bad way and the elec tape will help stop that.